# Apache ssl.conf SSLCipherSuite syntax: How to translate cypher suite names in underscore format to Apache?

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a list of cypher suites that my server must support for a third-party integration to Java 7u25 over TLSv1.2

The following are the suites that are needed:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Can someone help translate this to the proper syntax and/or advise where can I find a cross reference to find the syntax that Apache expects in ssl.conf under the SSLCipherSuite directive? (ie. ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link here: https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html

Apache uses the OpenSSL name format.

Another source is here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html